# Half node in sankey Highchart

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

Is there any way to draw a half node in Sankey using Highcharts?. I 
have searched a lot but didn't get any solution. From d3 it can be done but the same thing I want to achieve with Highcharts. For reference, I have attached the image. If you observe the nodes **Terminated before Institution, Terminated after institution, Pending Final Decision, Pending Institution Decision, and Other** all these are half nodes. So, is there any way I can do the same with Highcharts?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQGC.pngstrong text

Comment: Hi @john s, Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve? Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/en0uk9ad/ you can find an example with a basic sankey chart.

Comment: @ppotaczek Question is updated

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only easy way to do that seems to be to use a combination of `column` and `offset` node options:

```
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['China', 'EU', 94],
            ['China', 'US', 53]
        ],
        nodes: [{
            id: 'US',
            column: 1,
            offset: 110,
        }, {
            id: 'EU',
            offset: -70,
            column: 2
        }],
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x593vrtj/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.column

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.offset